# avd(x86 abi) can't run on Debian Server (no X11)

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

i have to run two AVD on a clean debian wheezy server(no X11 installed)

- debian server info:

  `Linux test 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- avd info:

  `Name: fengyun_m3u8_4.1.2
  Path: /home/op/.android/avd/fengyun_m3u8_4.1.2.avd
  Target: Android 4.1.2 (API level 16)
  Tag/ABI: default/armeabi-v7a
  Skin: WVGA800`

  `Name: fengyun_m3u8_4.1.2_x86
  Path: /home/op/.android/avd/fengyun_m3u8_4.1.2_x86.avd
  Target: Android 4.1.2 (API level 16)
  Tag/ABI: default/x86
  Skin: WVGA800`

when i use `emulator -avd fengyun_m3u8_4.1.2_x86 -no-window` to run avd, here come out some errors and `adb logcat` stuck in a loop

- command line error:

  `Failed to load lib64EGL_translator.so
  error libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  Failed to open lib64EGL_translator.so
  Failed to init_egl_dispatch
  emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES initialization failed!
  emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation library could not be initialized!
  emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
  emulator: warning: opening audio output failed`
- logcat loop: https://gist.github.com/atttx123/b6c7e572c925abb8d2dc
- adb devices:

  `emulator-5554   device
  emulator-5556   device`

p.s. when i run the arm avd use the same command, only get the `command line error`